# custom action method in controller but link_to is still pulling create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have created a deposit and withdrawl method in an accounts controller, and i have configured routes. i dont know what i am doing wrong, i get this error "Missing template accounts/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "c:/Users/geluna/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Luna-Kim-Kashkin/app/views"
  * "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

my accounts controller looks like this:

```
     class AccountsController < ApplicationController
     # before_action :set_account [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     before_filter :authenticate_user!

      respond_to :html

 def index
   # @accounts = Account.all
   @accounts = Account.where(id:current_user.id)
   if current_user.admin?
       @accounts = Account.all
   else
      @accounts = Account.where(email:current_user.email)
   end
       respond_with(@accounts)
   end

   def show
    if current_user.admin?
       @accounts = Account.all
    else
       @accounts = Account.where(email:current_user.email)
    end
        respond_with(@account)
    end

   def new
     @account = Account.new
     respond_with(@account)
   end

   def edit
     @accounts = Account.all
   end

   def create
     #@account = Account.new(account_params)
     # @account.save
     # respond_with(@account)
      end

     def update
      @account.update(account_params)
      respond_with(@account)
      end

     def destroy
        @account.destroy
        respond_with(@account)
     end

     def withdrawl
       @account = Account.new(account_params)
       @account.email = current_user.email
       @account.user_id = current_user.id
     end

    def deposit
       @account = Account.new(account_params)
       @account.email = current_user.email
       @account.user_id = current_user.id
       respond_to do |format|
       @account.save
    end
       redirect_to :root
     end 


   private
     def set_account
     #@accounts = Account.where(id:current_user.id)
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end

    def account_params
        # params[:account]
        params.require(:account).permit(:created_at, :email, :credit,   
        :debit, :acctbal, :depotype)
         end
```

my page with the link going to the new page which has an addfunds button that leads to the "new" page an you can add a float value and press submit button and it will add funds to account and display it on the previous page .

## Listing Accounts Inquiries

```
          <h2>Your Account information</h2>
       <table border="3">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Credit</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Account Balance</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>      
             <% @accounts.each do |account| %>   
                <tr>
                    <td><%= account.created_at %></td>
                    <td><b><font color="green">
             <%=number_to_currency(account.credit)%></b></td>       
                    <td><b><font color="red">
             <%=number_to_currency(account.debit)%></font></b></td> 
                    <td><b><%= number_to_currency(account.acctbal)%></b>    
              </td>     
                </tr>
                 <% end %>
                <tbody>     
            </table>
            </table>
            <%= link_to "Add Funds", depsoit_post_path(@post),
              method: :post, action: :deposit, :class => "btn btn-primary 
              btn-sm" %>

            <table>
            <thead>
             <tr>
             <th colspan="3"></th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
             <% if can? :manage, Users%>
             <tbody>
              <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
                <tr>
              <td><%= link_to 'Show', account %></td>
                 <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(account) %></td>
               <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', account, method: :delete, data: 
                {      confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
               </tr>
               <% end %>
                </tbody>
                </table>

                <br>

                 </div>
                 <% end %>
```

my routes.rb file
               Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
           devise_for :users
           get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
           get 'users/index'
           get 'accounts/index'

           get 'accounts/show'

           #get 'accounts/show'


           # resources :accounts

              resources :students
               #controller :sessions do
              #  get 'login' => :new
              #  post 'login' => :create
              #  delete 'logout' => :destroy
              #end

               root 'store#index', as: 'store'


             #get 'sessions/create'

             #get 'sessions/destroy'

              #resources :users

             resources :orders

             resources :line_items

               resources :carts

                get 'store/index'

             resources :menus
             resources :users

             resources :accounts do
             collection do
             post 'deposit', :action => :deposit
             post 'withdrawl', :action => :withdrawl

             end
             end
```

Comment: in your view, `= link_to "Add Funds", deposit_post_path(@post)` is misspelled. Also, try `deposit_path, method: :post, action: :deposit`

Answer (score 0):

Your routes looks wrong, change `collection` to `member`

```
resources :accounts do
  member do
     post 'deposit', :action => :deposit
     post 'withdrawl', :action => :withdrawl
  end
end
```

And resolve your misspelled path `depsoit_post_path` by checking `rake routes`

Comment: changed link_to "<%= link_to "Add Funds", deposit_account_path, method: :post, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

Comment: also changed routes to member as mentioned above, im getting this now, No route matches {:action=>"deposit", :controller=>"accounts"} missing required keys: [:id]. the rake routes says the URI pattern is                        deposit_account POST   /accounts/:id/deposit(.:format)           accounts#deposit .....seems like an :id is required???

Comment: yah required, give your account instance with it, like `deposit_account_path(account) `

Answer (score 0):

your routes and path seem wrong try:

```
resources :accounts do
    collection do
        post :deposit
        post :withdrawl
    end
end
```

I cant see why you need @post as a param for your link_to and I dont what you are using in that variable, but for a collection you don`t need it, if you want an :id param in the request, then change the above code to be 'member' instead of collection and it will automatically take the id column from whatever object you have in @post variable.

and with the above code, if you type in your terminal rake routes' you should find you have a path something along the lines of:

```
deposit_accounts_path
```

or

```
deposit_account_path
```

depending on whether you use collection or member

Comment: i add some messages to above comment as well. but i re did the link_to to try to follow the rake routes requirements <%= link_to "Add Funds", deposit_account_path(accounts_id: account), method: :post, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>     but it is saying undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x673e408>:0x54ded98> ....is this because it can not find account ? or account_id ? how would i fix this i have belong_to :user in the accounts.rb file at the top and has_many :accounts in the user.rb file.

Comment: Can you give me the whole error message? I can't see you directly referencing .user anywhere in the code, but I see you have a before_filter :authenticate_user! In your controller, which I'm assuming it's taking from the super class, I get the feeling it is coming from there maybe?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `account' for #<#<Class:0x55a45a0>:0x573de60> this is the error i get and its referencing to the link_to button. i have @accounts declared in the index method.. i dont know if that is the same variable it is pointing to in that particular parameter though

Comment: Oh well yeah, if you look at the view file, all of your other link_to 's are inside a loop for each account, but this link_to is floating in the middle outside of any scope or loop that has declared an 'account' variable to be referenced

Comment: the error that said user came because i changed "deposit_account_path(accounts_id: user)"  the account variable that isnt declared is when i put account in there instead of user? any ideas?

Comment: OH ok one sec let me loop it up

Comment: Same thing, no cape to a variable called user, but I have just realised your deposit method doesn't require any :id or :account_id, as you are creating a new Account object, so make sure your routes are as a collection and not a member, and then don't pass any parameters into the path name, just deposit_accounts_path

Comment: Working? Well that's a good first step then, a disappearing button however is not such a good step lol

Comment: i changed member to collection in routes and just have deposit_account_path and i have the link_to inside a loop identical to the loop the other links are in and the button is MIA, if i take it out of the loop the error comes back as, undefined local variable or method `deposit_account_path' for #<#<Class:0x53034a8>:0x3af5b28>

Comment: It needs to be accounts not account, collections use the pluralised version

Comment: the page opens with the button but when i press the button i got another animal, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /accounts/deposit... (and this underneith)param is missing or the value is empty: account and shows my  :                                                                                       def account_params
     # params[:account]
      params.require(:account).permit(:created_at, :email, :credit, :debit, :acctbal, :depotype)
    end

Comment: Try putting 'only' in front of the array after the before_filter, like: before_filter :set_account, only: [.......]

Comment: And no problem ;) always nice to both give and get help

Comment: i tried before_filter :set_account, only: :authenticate_user! and i tried before_filter only: :authenticate_user!  did you mean to add the array of action methods as well ?

Comment: @Edgar yeah I mean set_account and authenticate_user should be separate, I mean put the only inbetween the set_account and the array of actions: before_filter set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

Comment: i put this:                                                                                                        before_filter :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :deposit, :credit, :update, :destroy]
   before_filter :authenticate_user!                                                                 and it gives me an error:    Couldn't find Account without an ID                  def set_account
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: Because you have added :deposit into the array, take deposit out and it will be fine, you don't need to call set_account on deposit because you are making a new account :)

Comment: now its saying: param is missing or the value is empty: account and the params method it shows    def account_params
     (shows the line below highlighted)
      params.require(:account).permit(:created_at, :email, :credit, :debit, :acctbal, :depotype)
    end

Comment: Maybe because it is expecting params[:account] as you are putting in when creating your new account, but in your view you have no form setting these parameters, so you either need to create a form to set the parameters via user input, or in the controller don't use account_params, just use .new() and set the account objects variables manually

Comment: so like another _form.html.erb file inside the view/accounts folder?

Comment: kind of makes sense, when it was calling the create method it worked but it was using that form right? and if we use deposit method it cant use that same form?

Comment: i got this in my index.json.jbuilder file , json.array!(@accounts) do |account|
  json.extract! account, :id
  json.url account_url(account, format: :json)
end

Comment: Yeah, not unless you render the form into this view and then make the link_to as the forms action and use a submit button, various ways to go around it, but yeah, at the moment it's acting as a static link with no params

Comment: we can have 2  "_form.html.erb" files in this folder? how would i go about having 2 forms using 1 index.html.erb file ?

Comment: my partner wanted to stick the deposit method in the create action method and be done with it since it worked but i didnt like that because what if admin needs to modify something, but this is turning into a mission...lol

Comment: You can create a new form partial like _deposit_form.html.erb and use it for deposit, well if it works and you guys are okay with that then that's fine, but I always prefer to desperate and split things down to as small as possible, as it's more readable for others in large projects, but if that's not necessary then going with whatever works is fine!

Comment: ok i created that file and i copied the contents of _form.html.erb because that is basically what i want, how do i link that new partial with the params?

Comment: ok i went another way and it doesnt like the "+" in this line or the .sum() either.                                                                                                             `@account.acctbal = account_params[:deposit] + @previous_balance`